# Roll array, uniform circular shift

Tags: julia

Given an array:

`arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I would like to shift all the elements.

`shift!(arr, 2) => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]`

In Python, this is accomplished with Numpy using [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html#numpy-roll). How is this done in Julia?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need to implement it yourself, there is a built-in function for this

```
julia> circshift(arr, 2)  
5-element Array{Int64,1}: 
 4                        
 5                        
 1                        
 2                        
 3
```

It's also (slightly) more efficient than `roll2` proposed above:

```
julia> @btime circshift($arr, 2);
  68.563 ns (1 allocation: 128 bytes)

julia> @btime roll2($arr, 2);
  70.605 ns (4 allocations: 256 bytes)
```

Note, however, that none of the proposed functions operates in-place. They all create a new array. There is also the built-in `circshift!(dest, src, shift)` which operates in a preallocated `dest` (which, however, must be `!= src`).

Answer (score 2):

The function by Seanny123 does a lot of copying can be improved to have smaller memory footprint and execute faster. Consider:

```
function roll2(arr, step)
    len = length(arr)
    [view(arr,len-step+1:len); view(arr,1:len-step)]
end
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

And now the times (REPL output):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime roll($arr,2);
  124.254 ns (3 allocations: 400 bytes)

julia> @btime roll2($arr,2);
  73.386 ns (4 allocations: 288 bytes)
```

Of course the fastest way is to change `arr` in-place.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple function for this:

```
function roll(arr, step)
    return vcat(arr[end-step+1:end], arr[1:end-step])
end

println(roll(1:5, 2))
# => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
println(roll(1:6, 4))
# => [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
```